# Monitor computer temperature to a log file under Windows

Tags: windows, hardware

Occasionally, when playing video games, my computer will lock up and have to be restarted. It's always when playing *Battlefield 4* (the only game I play). Addmittedly, *BF4* has had significant problems, but I'm not sure if this is one caused by *BF4* or not.

The problem, to me, *seems to be* an overheating problem. However, whenever I look at the temperature, it never seems to be higher than 80 degrees Celsius, which should not cause a lockup, and often is in the mid-60s. To monitor this, I use *Open Hardware Monitor*, which does *not* have the capability to write to a logfile.

I need a program that records temperature to a logfile continuously, and closes the log file so that it is not corrupted on a forced shutdown, since I have to do this every time it locks up. Does anyone have any recommendations along with *how to set up the logging*?

I run Windows 7. The motherboard is an MSI ATX Z87-G45 (LGA 1150).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a little testing, and [coretemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) seems to do this. The installer contains some [semi-adwarish](http://www.installiqlearnmore.com/installiq_learnmore_w.html) components, so I ended up using the portable version on the same page under more downloads

It creates a nice CSV file you can load into a spreadsheet like Openoffice, and it seems to log every 10 seconds by default if you turn on logging. It seems resilient to sudden shutdowns to an extent, though, admittedly, I did not simulate a sudden shutdown of the whole system, merely a process kill.

[image]

With the installed version, you should be able to get it to run on startup, but between the installer adware, and the issue ONLY being caused by a single game, its a good option.

Comment: Where does it store the log? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It's in the same location as the .exe. Also make sure to actually enable it via Tools > Logging on (F4).

Answer (score 0):

[RealTemp](https://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/) does this. It's a portable app, you can specify the logging interval and can even output to CSV.

[image]

[image: CSV Output]